# reading a weird format .mvc

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc

I am doing some custom development for a client on their miva shopping cart site and the format is .mvc

The site appears to mostly have this format and I have no idea how to read it. Any ideas

Comment: Can you provide an excerpt of a file using this format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my (limited) understanding of Miva, the scripts can be compiled (protecting the source among other things). I believe `.mvc` is a *complied* Miva script.

Comment: the problem is I am a web developer and I need to read the source code

Comment: @John I understand, I think Miva may provide an application that reads *some* compiled scripts, but some scripts are compiled to protect the source (not just for performance). In fact, I'd guess that the main reason Miva has compiled scripts is source code protection.

Comment: Yes, .mvc is a compiled script. The source code cannot be read.